# Rails: Where to put script/function that runs only when starting server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, initializer

I am using the [Predictor gem](https://github.com/Pathgather/predictor) for a recommendation system. I want to write a script to initialize the recommender when running `rails server`. If I put the script into the `initializers/`dirctory, it will also be run whenever `rake` is executed.

Is there a way to add scripts are executed only when running `rails server`?

Answer (score 1):

Thought it is not recommended, you could update the file `bin/rails`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

puts "Write your custom code here"

APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application',  __FILE__)
require_relative '../config/boot'
require 'rails/commands'
```

This runs whenever `rails s`, `rails c` or any rails command is called.